# Comparing 2 folders with filecmp is not working

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, file-management

i try to compare 2 folders if the are equal inside -

I tried it with this code

```
print(path)
print(toPath)
print(filecmp.cmp(path, toPath))
```

but the output is always

```
C:\Users\Polzi\Documents\DEV\userza123\OLD_STRUCTURE\Billing\customers\2020\01\ZAT201
C:\Users\Polzi\Documents\DEV\userza123\NEW_STRUCTURE\Billing\customers\ZAT201\2020\01
False
```

But from my point of view they are both 100 percent equal:

Folder1:

[image]

Folder2:

[image]

Any ideas why are these 2 folders different according the filecmp.cmp function?

Comment: Does [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68522286/comparing-2-folders-with-filecmp-is-not-working/68522331#68522331) solves your issue? If yes then don't forget to mark this as accepted answer and if any queries ask in comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to use [`dircmp`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/filecmp.html#the-dircmp-class) rather then [`filecmp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html#module-filecmp).
**filecmp :**

> Compare the files named f1 and f2, returning True if they seem equal, False otherwise.

**dircmp :**

> Construct a new directory comparison object, to compare the directories a and b.

Comment: @Rapid1898 Then, mark this answer as accepted